# Fundamentally understanding 3 or more table sql joins

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I apologize for the long question in advance.  Most online articles don't go over this, they just show a quick result set.  For such an important and commonly used idea, I want to fully understand this.  I've seen a lot of the post on here with specific examples, but none got the core idea in my head.  My question is when you do a 3+ table join, how does this work in memory?  The statement I'm currently using is:

```
select a.cust_id, a.[first name],a.[last name],a.[primary zip],c.jerseynum
from contact as a
join notes as b
on a.cust_id = b.cust_id
join jerseytable as c
on a.cust_id = c.cust_id
```

so after the first join between a and b we get a result set, we'll call it 1
I then do a join on a and c... this is were it gets fuzzy for me.  This result set doesn't just take the place of my previous join, does it only add records to 1 that fit just the join between a and c?

Comment: Read the wikipedia article about basic relational algebra and google for query optimization if you want to understand this topic. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra

Comment: If you are wondering about how things work in memory, **PLEASE SPECIFY WHICH DATABASE** - MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: I think this is NARQ since he is asking for internals and didn't/won't specify a datbase implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a joined with b, then the result set is joined with c.
(If you use MS SQL Server, you can see this process in query execution plan).

Answer (score 3):

You're basically asking how a database does its query execution.  There's a lot of theory and practice in this area, more than a single answer can give you.

The query engine has a lot of tools at its disposal, depending on the joins, the indexes, and other statistics it keeps.  It can construct in-memory tables, reorder joins (in some cases) to better limit the number of returned rows.  It might identify the results of the different joins and merge them together.

Read up on query plans to get started:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan and the related section on query optimization.

Comment: i was asking what i wrote, you have your first join on table a and b.  This gives you a table we'll say table 1.  If I then join on table a and c , does it compare my table 1 which is already in memory or does it just make another table a and c.  Thats where im confused, i was hoping someone could go over the step by step. Overall when you do multiple joins you end up with one table and im not understanding how.

Comment: What I'm saying is -- it might not even compare tables a and b first.  It might do a and c first, it might do a and c and a and b separately, then combine them.  There is no single answer to this question, as what the database does to interpret a query and provide a result is an extraordinarily complex set of operations and calculations, detailed somewhat in the links I provided.

Answer (score 3):

`JOIN` is a relational operator: it takes two relations as parameters and the result is another relation.

Relational operators can be strung together. Consider your query written in the relational language Tutorial D:

Assuming `x` and `y` are suitably declared relation variables (relvars):

```
x := a MATCHING b; 
y := x JOIN c {jerseynum};
```

Alternatively:

```
y := a JOIN c {jerseynum};
x := y MATCHING b;
```

However, the above forces an order of execution on the optimizer: assigning the intermediate results to relvars is essentially telling the optimizer how to do it's job (i.e. not good). They can be strung together e.g. as follows:

```
a MATCHING b JOIN c {jerseynum};
```

The SQL `FROM` clause works in a similar way i.e. no need to assign to intermediate (derived) tables. The optimizer is free to evaluate them in any order it sees fit. Trust the optimizer :)

Answer (score 1):

After it parsed your query, the database engine will generate a *plan* which describes the actual steps to be taken to get the results of the query. You should examine your actual plan to get an insight what is really going on. 
Basically the optimizer will choose the order of joins regardless of the order you wrote in the sql. The actual order of joins will depend among other things on the indexes and on the statistics kept on the data.
see this article on query optimizer http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/76059/pods98-tutorial.pdf

Comment: @JNK, my answer is totally not related to MS SQL Server in any ways. Also, the article I linked is totally general and scientific and does not have any more relation to MS SQL Server then the fact that it is hosted on microsoft.com. So, everything is just fine.